# Wiring can lights

Tags: switch

I have installed a fan/light kit with 2 switches.  I want to add can lights also on a separate switch.  Can I tie into the fan/light wiring to do this?

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the box for the fan/light?

Comment: Please provide details on the wiring/feeds for the fan/light and two switches. Do you want two switches on the can light also?